# java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, easymock

I am using EasyMock to create mock classes in test cases.

```
expect(entity.getType()).andReturn("string");
```

Type belongs to the `String` datatype. In my development environment it is working fine. But If I transfer to my server and take build, it is failing with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type
```

I don't know why it is failing in server and getting executed in my development machine.

Development EasyMock version: 2.5.2

Comment: What is the type of `entity` and how exactly is `getType()` declared?

Comment: Class Entity { private String type; }

Comment: If what you have said is correct it means only one thing. There are two different versions of your class (or perhaps even the entire jar) at the server and your dev. machine. Also, it may be worth including a System.out.println(entity.getType().getClass()) statement before setting the mock return.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

I had a partial mock in `EasyMock`, but forgot to call `addMockedMethod` for the method I wanted to set the expectation for.

The error message was the same as above, I'd say that was somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 10):

In my case the method was `final` on which I called `expect` on. So `EasyMock` was not able to mock the method and thus did not record the method invocation.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your `entity` object is not a simple POJO (eg. `new Entity()`), and it was created with the `createMock()` methods of EasyMock.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to remember to call reset(...) on it after having used it once, or I (bizarrely) got this error message calling expect on it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this error when trying to mock behavior of a class's `toString()` method, e.g. `expect(entity.toString()).andReturn("string");`, EasyMock will instead invoke a special version of the `toString()` method on that line in the test, and will not modify the expected behavior of the method in the code under test. You basically can't mock any toString() behavior, and your test will liekly still pass if you just remove the line where you're trying to mock the call. PowerMock does not seem to offer any solutions in this case, since its `@PrepareForTest` doesn't change this behavior.